# How to display JSON object in scrollView

Tags: android, json, scrollview

**I want to display each JSON object in horizontal scroll view separately** *Means id in separate horizontal scroll view and same for resType, name and URL.So I will have total of 4 horizontal scroll views*

```
      JsonObjectRequest jor = new  JsonObjectRequest(url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()  {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    try {                         

                        JSONArray ja = response.getJSONArray("results");

                        ArrayList<Details> myModelList = new    ArrayList<Details>();
                        Details mymodel = null;
                        for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {

                            JSONObject jsonObject = ja.getJSONObject(i);
                            mymodel = new Details();
                            mymodel.id = Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.optString("id").toString());
                            mymodel.url = jsonObject.getString("resLink");
                            mymodel.resType = jsonObject.getString("resType");
                            mymodel.name = jsonObject.getString("resName");

                            myModelList.add(mymodel);
                              // setData();
                            //

                        }


                    }catch(JSONException e){e.printStackTrace();}
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ***HorizontalScrollView*** for this. Here's some code to get you started. First is you can create a layout using the HorizontalScrollView with a ***TextView*** inside it where you will put the String (or whichever value you want to put).

> hor_scrl_view_item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        />

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Next is you put a view that will serve as a container for the List of HorizontalScrollView.

> activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:weightSum="5"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then add HorizontalScrollViews to the container view dynamically.

> MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private LinearLayout llMain;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initViews();
    }


    private void initViews() {
        llMain = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);

        List<String> ids = Arrays.asList("1732150721937507n15498017b329587b213985v7b2159832175bv980127b59817b295v87b219857b2198075v9017",
                "21938579817v98219857b13215v982175bv982175v9018275v980217bv52",
                "2935871n2980v7b25987b98712375bv9832175bv9821735b9802137b5v90215v9821375bv9802175bv982175v9802175v98175vb980217b5v98017bv3");

        for (int i = 0; i < ids.size(); i++) {
            llMain.addView(addNewItem(ids.get(i)));
        }

    }

    private HorizontalScrollView addNewItem(String str) {
        HorizontalScrollView sv = (HorizontalScrollView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.json_details_scrollview, null);
        TextView tv = (TextView) sv.findViewById(R.id.tv);
        tv.setText(str);

        return sv;
    }

}
```

Here is a screenshot after I run it.

[image]

Hope this helps. :)